# In Redux, how do I render state for 2 clients that are able to change the same state?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

My problem is I don't know how to update the state of my redux app where 2 users are able to edit the same state. So I have a Redux ios app where the state is initially:
    { isPlaying: False }

for 2 client iphones. The app has just 1 play song button. When one of the users presses `play` the song begins playing on both iphones and when one user presses `pause` the song pauses on both iphones(I want this behavior). I do this by sending an action that hits my reducer to play or pause the song.

Then I have a event listener outside my reducer that updates the state when I receive a websocket message of the other user pressing play or pause.

`QUESTION` So when `user1` presses `play` the song begins playing for `user1` and `user2` however the `render()` function is only called for `user1`. How do I also call the `render()` function for `user2` to?

Websocket Message Event Listener:

```
ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  // a message was received
  let message = JSON.parse(e.data);
  if (message.type === 'pause') {
    currentSong.pause(); // HOW DO I ALSO CALL COMPONENT RENDER() FUNCTION?
    console.log('pausing: server websocket message');
  } else if (message.type === 'play') {
    currentSong.setCurrentTime(message.currentTime);
    currentSong.play((success) => {
      if (success) {
        console.log('playing: server websocket message');
      } else {
        console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Reducer Function:

```
export default function(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CLICK_PLAY_PAUSE_BUTTON:
            let newState = cloneObject(state);
            newState.isPlaying = !state.isPlaying;

            if (newState.isPlaying) {
                currentSong.play(success => {
                    // Can't figure out why this callback never calls!
                    if (success) {
                        console.log('successfully finished playing: button pressed');
                    } else {
                        console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
                    }
                });

                currentSong.getCurrentTime(seconds => {
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'play', currentTime: seconds, name: userName }));
                });
            } else {
                currentSong.pause();
                currentSong.getCurrentTime(seconds => {
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'pause', currentTime: seconds, name: userName }));
                });
            }

            return newState;
        default:
            // if state is undefined return newState instead
            // of boolean
            return state || newState;
    }
};
```

Comment: you shouldn't put async functions in your reducer. reducers must be pure.Moving those async logic into actions would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you have a few things out of place which is compounding the problem. Like @Phi Nguyen has mentioned in the comments, removing the async stuff from the reducer is the first step to take.

After that you need to consider what is going on with your `play()` and `pause()` methods. I don't know what is going on with them, its hard to tell without more code, but if you are intending for them to change state (such as the song being played/paused) you should be dispatching/using actions, after which your reducers shoudl respond correclty.